# What have you done or what did you do?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

Suppose a child is accused of misbehaviour and the parent wants to know what the child has done. Would it be okay to ask the child: "what have you done?" or should they say "what did you do?". Is there a difference in nuance? Does "what have you done?" sound more accusatory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between Present Perfect and Past Simple ( I am not a beginner )](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/173685/difference-between-present-perfect-and-past-simple-i-am-not-a-beginner) Also [“Have you seen her?” or “Did you see her?”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23275) and [“Have you done a poo?” vs. “Did you poo?”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/239525), among others

Comment: The only reason you think ***What have you done**?* sounds more "accusatory" is because the ***Present Perfect*** form implies a strong connection to time of utterance. And very often the reason for asking such a question in the first place is because ***something is obviously wrong*** about the current situation (so speaker is asking for an explanation from whoever seems likely to have caused the problem). But since the same words are often used in *non-accusatory* contexts (again, where knowing about a *past* action is relevant to the present) it doesn't really have negative connotations.

Answer (score 0):

> ***What have you done?***

does sound as an accusation in this situation. However, I don't think ***what did you do?*** is particularly better. If you want to avoid anguishing the child, you could say:

> (Can you tell me) what happened?

or, showing more concern

> (Can you tell me) what happened to you?